# How to perform authorization with external authenticate

Tags: spring-security, authorization

Im applying Spring Security for my Spring Boot application, for the part `authentication`, i have 3rd party to do it, basically, when user access website, the gateway will navigate user to a central login platform to do authenticate. If user login successfully, a special key will be append for every later HttpServletRequest.

From my Controller, i just need to extract authenticated user from request. 
So now i have question, if i want to use Authorization feature from Spring Security, how do i inject the user `info` (username, email) and `role` from request to spring authorization process? 
Because i want to validate user access to some specific url, like `/admin/**` only can access by role `admin`

i see we can create user detail like this:

```java
public class SecurityUser implements UserDetails{
    String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

    String userName;
    String password;
    String role;

    public SecurityUser(String username, String password, String role){
        this.userName = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        list.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + role));

        return list;
    }
```

and user detail service

```java
public class DefaultUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //How to create user detail with information from httprequest?
        return null;
    }
}
```

But i only have `username` and `role` from httpRequest from 3rd party. How do i collect it?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the section of the reference docs on [Pre-Authentication Scenarios](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/authentication/preauth.html). You can either extend `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` or construct and configure a `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

spring-security user `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` that extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` do authentication

maybe you need a new `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to replace `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.